# Display JSON data in console.log

Tags: json

I have here JSON array:

```
[{"date":"2017-03-04"},{"date":"2017-03-05"},{"date":"2017-03-06"},{"date":"2017-03-07"},{"date":"2017-03-08"},{"date":"2017-03-09"},{"date":"2017-03-10"},{"date":"2017-03-11"},{"date":"2017-03-12"},{"date":"2017-03-13"},{"date":"2017-03-14"},{"date":"2017-03-15"},{"date":"2017-03-16"},{"date":"2017-03-17"},{"date":"2017-03-18"},{"date":"2017-03-19"},{"date":"2017-03-20"},{"date":"2017-03-21"},{"date":"2017-03-22"},{"date":"2017-03-23"},{"date":"2017-03-24"},{"date":"2017-03-25"},{"date":"2017-03-26"},{"date":"2017-03-27"},{"date":"2017-03-28"},{"date":"2017-03-29"},{"date":"2017-03-30"},{"date":"2017-03-31"},{"date":"2017-04-01"},{"date":"2017-04-02"},{"date":"2017-04-03"},{"date":"2017-04-04"},{"date":"2017-04-05"},{"date":"2017-04-06"},{"date":"2017-04-07"},{"date":"2017-04-08"},{"date":"2017-04-09"},{"date":"2017-04-10"},{"date":"2017-04-11"},{"date":"2017-04-12"},{"date":"2017-04-13"},{"date":"2017-04-14"},{"date":"2017-04-15"},{"date":"2017-04-16"},{"date":"2017-04-17"},{"date":"2017-04-18"},{"date":"2017-04-19"},{"date":"2017-04-20"},{"date":"2017-04-21"},{"date":"2017-04-22"},{"date":"2017-04-23"},{"date":"2017-04-24"},{"date":"2017-04-25"},{"date":"2017-04-26"},{"date":"2017-04-27"},{"date":"2017-04-28"},{"date":"2017-04-29"},{"date":"2017-04-30"},{"date":"2017-05-01"},{"date":"2017-05-02"},{"date":"2017-05-03"},{"date":"2017-05-04"},{"date":"2017-05-05"},{"date":"2017-05-06"},{"date":"2017-05-07"},{"date":"2017-05-08"},{"date":"2017-05-09"},{"date":"2017-05-10"},{"date":"2017-05-11"},{"date":"2017-05-12"},{"date":"2017-05-13"},{"date":"2017-05-14"},{"date":"2017-05-15"},{"date":"2017-05-16"},{"date":"2017-05-17"},{"date":"2017-05-18"},{"date":"2017-05-19"},{"date":"2017-05-20"},{"date":"2017-05-21"},{"date":"2017-05-22"},{"date":"2017-05-23"},{"date":"2017-05-24"}]
```

All I want is to display it via console.log. This is my code:

```
     $.ajax({
        url: apiUrl,
        type: 'GET',
        success: function (r) {
            for( var a=0; a< r.length; a++){
                console.log(r[a].date);
            }
        },error: function(){
            console.log("error");
        }
    });
```

but it shows undefined in console.log.

Thanks.

[Image as reference](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U8bvt.png)

Comment: what you get when `console.log(r)`

Answer (score -1):

Try using:
`console.log(JSON.stringify(data[a].date));`

Comment: You cannot print an object in the console? That's news to me. Also, OP isn't logging an object, they're logging a string.

Comment: I mean directly we can't print..we have to convert it into string.

Comment: Well… still no. I'm logging objects in my console all day long. Arguably it depends on your console/browser, but all modern browsers do it just fine.

Comment: ok, may be I have not experienced it yet.I am new to this, so till now what I have experienced I think it should work.Taking back my answer.

Answer (score -1):

I already got it. I just use $.parseJSON(r). Thanks everyone.

Comment: Or set the appropriate options on your AJAX request so jQuery does it for you…